# Segmentation fault in alphabetical linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a segmentation fault occurring in my alphabetical linked list and I pinned it down to the prev in the last else statement.

```
else 
{
    prev->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

```
int add(char *str, char *file) {
struct word_node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct word_node));

unsigned len = strlen(str) + 1;
char *s = malloc(len);
memcpy(s, str, len);

new_node->data = s;
new_node->count = 1;
new_node->filename = file;
new_node->next = NULL;

// struct word_node 

if (head == NULL)
{
    head = new_node;
    return 0;
}

struct word_node* ptr = head;
struct word_node* prev = NULL;

while (ptr != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(ptr->data, new_node->data) > 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
}

if (ptr == head)
{
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
    return 0;
}
else 
{
    prev->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = ptr;
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: @tadman I don't understand. I did ptr == head. I tested with ptr == head and ptr == NULL and I see get a segmentation fault on both.

Comment: It's worth noting that `head` should be an argument to this function, not a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this while loop

```
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(ptr->data, new_node->data) > 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

you forgot to update the pointer `prev` as for example

```
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(ptr->data, new_node->data) > 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    prev = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code simplifies to:

```c
struct word_node* prev = NULL;

prev->next = new_node;
```

See the problem now?

To run that second line you must initialize `prev` to something valid before using it.

Comment: Yea, I'm accessing a null node. However, I used this strategy for another program of mine and it worked. Should I initialize the prev node somehow?

Comment: You **cannot** de-reference a `NULL` pointer and expect your code to work, especially not when altering data at that location. This is one of the most fundamental rules of pointers. I doubt this "worked" in your other code.You may be mistaken, as what you were doing was likely different. This code is an automatic and immediate segmentation fault on most systems.

Comment: Also from algorithm point of view prev must reference a node (the previous one), in this case it points to nowhere since it's null. You can have prev->next == NULL, but not prev, or else it's exactly like @tadman mentioned.